# JSON data not able to capture

Tags: java, json

I write a program to capture the JSON response from the server which contain some needed information I needed. I discovered that sometime my program will not able to capture the correct JSON string and sometime it's works well with no problem. I try to check my code for capturing the response and have no idea on it. When I check the JSON string from server, it's contain the field I want but my program not able to capture the correct data.

This is my JSON String

```
"info":{  
      "reason":"Fine",
      "boolean":false,
      "post":{  
         "actions":"",
         "actions_In_process":"Checked",
         "destination":"C%3ApdfFdoc%20edipdfFdestinationpdfFexample.pdf",
         "file_type":"pdf",
       
      },
```

This is my program for capture the JSON string and the field I need is `action_In_process`

```
String Url1 = "http://IP:port/etc/";
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) Url1.openConnection();  
con.setRequestMethod("GET");
con.connect();
int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
if(responseCode == 200)
{
  try
   {
     InputStream is = con.getInputStream();
     BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(is));
     StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
     String data = "" ; 
     while((data = read.readLine() ) != null )
     {
         buffer.append(data);
     }

     String JsonData = buffer.toString();
     JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(JsonData);
     JSONObject process_info = jobj.getJSONObject("info");
     JSONObject pi = process_info.getJSONObject("post");
     String action_run = pi.getString("actions_In_process");
     System.out.println("Process:" +action_run);
```

What I had found out is sometime the Process showing is blank but when I get back the JSON data and I found out the field I need is inside the JSON response. Please share your opinion on this issues

This is the message showing my compiler if I not able to capture the correct JSON string

```
Process :
```

If in normal condition

```
Process : check
```

Comment: use jsonlint.com to validate your json string

Comment: Your "JSON String" is not valid JSON.

Comment: @ScaryWombat - i have validated, it's contain the data i want but my program not able to retrieve it

Comment: Read the comment by @Henry

Comment: Your json is not valid. your json should be like `{
  "info": {
    "reason": "Fine",
    "boolean": false,
    "post": {
      "actions": "",
      "actions_In_process": "Checked",
      "destination": "C%3ApdfFdoc%20edipdfFdestinationpdfFexample.pdf",
      "file_type": "pdf"
    }
  }
}`

Comment: What is stopping you from checking `action_run.length() == 0`?

Comment: @NitinVavdiya - this JSON string is one portion of the super long JSON data from server, i can post the full one if need

Comment: @cricket_007 - May you explain a bit further? can't get what your means?

Comment: Can you explain your problem further? You are getting an empty string. What is the problem with that? There are no exceptions in your JSON parsing. You are able to "capture the data" just fine.

Comment: I request you add sysouts and print the responsecode and also the json string that is created. I do not see any else part which is handling other response code. Ideally response code 200 is only received from server is everything is ok, other for anything else you may get 404 or 500 etc....

Answer (score -1):

BufferedReader's readline() is blocking.

Comment: So? What is the fix to that? How else are you supposed to read an InputSteam to a string?

Comment: My English is not good, I can only provide a direction to you, you can from this direction to solve the problem.

Comment: You can use Google Translate. You don't have to force yourself to try to write in English. The fact that the method is blocking is not a problem, though